# When using cleft sentence using 'it', do we use that or what?

Tags: sentence, clefts

Are these sentences grammatically correct? I looked at different sites, but none mention whether using 'what' would be wrong.

"It was his lying what hurt the most." 
"It was the shrimp what made her sick."
"It was his being rude what bothered them the most."
"It is global warming what we should be the most worried about."
"It was the protest what caused the traffic jams."

Comment: I believe that some dialects of English use *what* like this. It is considered incorrect in standard dialects, though.

Comment: Thank you! I’ve looked and looked and couldn’t find anything on this specific topic. This clears things out.

Comment: If you Google "man what done it," you can find some discussions of this topic. 
Looking at a few of these discussions, however, I wasn't that impressed by any of them (for example, I'd like to know *where* this is used). I'm sure there are better discussions of it somewhere on the web, but I have no idea how to find them.

Comment: The final clause in an _It_-cleft sentence is a relative clause. _That_ and _which_ can be used in relative clauses, but _what_ cannot.